# Hiding drawings in Google Sheets with App Script (Or keeping them in hidden columns)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hope I'm just missing something obvious.
I have a google Sheet with several sections of columns that are beeing hidden to simulate sort of different views. Each of these sections have buttons (drawings) to trigger scripts which may or may not hide columns (they do hide columns).
Now when I hide all columns to the left, all the buttons (drawings) that were in those, now hidden, columns will cluster on the remaining visible columns and even with drawing.setPosition they refuse to move to the hidden columns.
When the columns to right are beeing hidden this does not occur.

I want to either hide or move the buttons to hidden columns, I don't want to see buttons that are supposed to be in hidden columns. They haunt me, please help!

(Removing them is not an option since I'll need them back when the columns are no longer hidden)

Regards,
Woof

I tried moving them to the hidden columns and expected that to work because in the case of the columns to the right beeing hidden the drawings can obviously occupy a hidden column.

Comment: trigger the scripts with a menu item.

Comment: @MattKing thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I had the brilliant idea to design sort of a user interface with the intention of having it look pretty. So I'm stuck with Buttons. This is a function follows design case, otherwise your suggestion would be favourable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have scripts or macros assigned to each drawing (eg so buttons run an action when clicked)? You do this by right-clicking on a drawing and choosing Assign Script.

If so, you can **use the script/macro name** you've assigned to look up and reference a specific drawing using the `getDrawings()` method in apps script which enumerates all the properties of a drawing (height, width, assigned script onAction, etc.). The key is once you have those properties, you can change them using `.setValue()` in apps script.

**PART 1: Hiding a button**

"Hiding" the button is as simple as setting the height and width of a specified drawing to 1 pixel. It will still exist on the sheet, but is effectively invisible to the user. This script assumes you know the "button name" (the script/macro assigned to the drawing):

```
function hideButton() {
  var button = "showSheetID"; // replace with your drawing's onAction() value
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var configSheet = ss.getSheetByName(YOUR_SHEET_NAME);
  var drawings = configSheet.getDrawings();
  for (var i = 0; i < drawings.length; i++) {
  if(drawings[i].getOnAction() === button){
    var height = 1;
    var width = 1;
    drawings[i].setHeight(height).setWidth(width);
  }
}
}
```

**PART 2: Showing a button you've hidden**

I'd been trying to solve this for a year, the code is somewhat lengthy but straightforward.

"Showing" a hidden button is as easy as restoring its original height/width. However, this requires knowing what the original dimensions of the drawing were. Here's how I tackled that part:

1. Start by getting all the buttons on your sheet and their properties. Note that `getOnAction` returns the assigned script/macro as a string, which you can use as the button name for lookup purposes later. You only need to get `onAction`, `height`, and `width` for your use case - the script below grabs all properties of each drawing for illustrative purposes.

```
    // Returns the script/macro name and positioning of all drawings that have attached scripts/macros on a given sheet.
    function getButtons() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var configSheet = ss.getSheetByName(YOUR_SHEET_NAME);
      var drawings = configSheet.getDrawings();
      var results = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < drawings.length; i++) {
      if(drawings[i].getOnAction().length > 1){
        var action = drawings[i].getOnAction();
        var height = drawings[i].getHeight();
        var width = drawings[i].getWidth();
        var col = drawings[i].getContainerInfo().getAnchorColumn();
        var row = drawings[i].getContainerInfo().getAnchorRow();
        var xOff = drawings[i].getContainerInfo().getOffsetX();
        var yOff = drawings[i].getContainerInfo().getOffsetY();
        var zIndx = drawings[i].getZIndex();
        
        var positions = [action,height,width,col,row,xOff,yOff,zIndx];
        results = results.concat([positions]);
        }
      } 
    Logger.log(results);
    return results;
  }
```

2. Create a new function that calls the `getButtons` function, and stores the results somewhere - in my case I created a separate `Buttons` sheet and wrote the results to that sheet.

```
// Run once during setup when buttons are in original positions to store values for hiding and showing later.
function storeButtons() { 
      var data = getButtons();
      var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(BUTTONS_SHEET_NAME).getLastRow();
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(BUTTONS_SHEET_NAME)
  .getRange(lastRow + 1,1,data.length, data[0].length)
  .setValues(data);
}
```

The BUTTONS sheet will look something like this:
[table listing button properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9XN6.png)

3. Show the button by looking up its original height and width on the BUTTONS sheet and setting these values. I used a helper function `buttonRow()` to do the lookup.

```
// Returns row number of a given button on Buttons sheet so its params can be accessed elsewhere
function buttonRow(button) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  Logger.log("Button is " + button);
  var buttonVals = ss.getRange("Buttons!1:A10").getValues();
  
  for (var i=0; i < buttonVals.length; i++) { // going through all the rows
    var row = 1+i;
    if (buttonVals[i][0] == button) {
      Logger.log("The " + button + " button params are in row " + row);
      return row;     
    }
    }
}

function showButton(){
  var button = "showSheetID"; // replace with your drawing's onAction() value
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var configSheet = ss.getSheetByName(YOUR_SHEET_NAME);
  var buttonsSheet = ss.getSheetByName(BUTTONS_SHEET_NAME);
  var drawings = configSheet.getDrawings();
  var row = buttonRow(button); // returns the row number on the BUTTONS sheet where you've stored the dimensions
  for (var i = 0; i < drawings.length; i++) {
  if(drawings[i].getOnAction() === button){
    var height = buttonsSheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
    var width = buttonsSheet.getRange(row,3).getValue();
    drawings[i].setHeight(height).setWidth(width);
  }
}
}
```

Hope this is helpful for you! Happy to troubleshoot if you run into issues.

Comment: Hey, this is a really nice solution to my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find a solution I solved my issue with a workaround instead.
As I have already described, the issue only arrises, when the Buttons (Drawings) I try to hide are in hidden columns to the left, not to the right. My workaround now is:
I added more Columns to the right, which are alway hidden, and move all Buttons (Drawings) which I currently don't need over there.
I can identifiy the drawings via the function attached to them, maybe this helps people with similar issues.

If someone finds an actual solution to this problem I would be very interested!